# IDA Pro Plugin to add x64dbg

Tags: ida-plugin, x64dbg

Is there a plugin for IDA Pro to enable me to add x64dbg debugger support to IDA Pro 6.8 or 6.9?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to create debugger plugins for IDA Pro.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov    Humm,  The IDA SDK includes an example of a debugger plugin.

Comment: It is possible to create debugger plugins for IDA Pro. Reference http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/creating-ida-pro-debugger-plugins-api-documentation-and-examples .

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any fully-fledged plugin, but there are some halfway solutions.

[Labeless](https://github.com/a1ext/labeless) looks promising and provides

> Labels/Comments synchronization between IDA PRO and dbg backend (OllyDbg1.10, OllyDbg 2.01, x64dbg)

Another solution is [ret-sync](https://github.com/tmr232/ret-sync) (or [here](https://github.com/bootleg/ret-sync)). It syncs your current address between IDA and various debuggers, and allows for basic command passing.

None of those provide a true debugger interface, but they do make life easier.